# How to make an asset allocation line graph in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

[image]

Can someone please let me know what kind of graph this is called?

I am running an asset allocation with different risk/return combinations and would like to show the change in asset allocation through a graph.

The graph shown has time on the x axis and I would like to change that to increase in risk (volatility) Thank you so much!

I am not sure what in Matplot this is called but have no luck finding the right graph to do so.

Comment: That kind of plot is typically called a "sand chart" because it looks like somebody poured in colored sand from the top.  https://medium.com/@tbarrasso/plotly-tip-5-sand-charts-c8331bfa3dee

Comment: Thanks. I googled using sand chart and find the solution. It's called Stacked Area Chart.

Answer (score 0):

there is powerful package plotly. It has lots of plot types and python api, you can check examples here https://plotly.com/python/. There are some which might suit for you
Take a look to contour plot https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/ and https://plotly.com/python/knn-classification/#probability-estimates-with-gocontour